# Best way to model these ears

Tags: modeling

I recently started 3D Modeling. Trying to model this chair and having the hardest time figuring out how to model the shape of the ears just right. Any tip would be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange! This question is kinda broad... There must something in specifics that's making you ask this question. Something that you can't get quite right.

Comment: You also seem to have already answered your own question with the second image showing a pretty good topology for the geometry in question